# how to fix it following output

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

no rule, use for any inbuild function, i have a number of forms and different edition dates so i showing sample data. first, i am matched check the FORM_NO column the last four digits with the Edition_Date column. if matched then the FORM_NO column the last four digits are skipped and concatenations with the Edition_Date column else as it is show.For example when i am trying below query executed.

```
 with FOrm as (select 'GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD' Form_No, '05-05' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'CM59930202' Form_No, '02-02' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select '99109 06 08' Form_No, '06-08' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'IM 7978 08 12' Form_No, '08-12' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'IL01220907' Form_No, '09-07' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'PRG 2023 05 14' Form_No, '05-14' Edition_Date from dual)
select Form_No,case when SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE( Form_No, '[^[:alnum:]]', NULL ),-4)=REGEXP_REPLACE( Edition_Date, '[^[:alnum:]]', NULL )
then substr(Form_No, 0, length(Form_No)-4)||' '||Edition_Date end as REC1,

 case when SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE( Form_No, '[^[:alnum:]]', NULL ),-4)=REGEXP_REPLACE( Edition_Date, '[^[:alnum:]]', NULL )
 then substr(Form_No, 0, length(REGEXP_REPLACE( Form_No, '[^[:alnum:]]', NULL ))-4)||' '||Edition_Date 
  when  regexp_count(Form_No,'[^ [:alnum:]]')>2  then Form_No||' '||Edition_Date 
  when  regexp_count(Form_No,'[^-[:alnum:]]')>2  then SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE( Form_No, '[^[:alnum:]]', NULL ),-5)||' '||Edition_Date 
 end REC2 from FOrm
```

I showed the following output after executing the query

```
        FORM_NO                         Edition_Date        REC1                REC2
----------------------------    -------------   ----------------    --------------------
GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD     05-05               NULL                GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD 05-05
CM59930202                      02-02               CM5993 02-02        CM5993 02-02
99109 06 08                     06-08               99109 0 06-08       99109 06-08
IM 7978 08 12                   08-12               IM 7978 0 08-12     IM 797 08-12
IL01220907                      09-07               IL0122 09-07        IL0122 09-07
PRG 2023 05 14                  05-14               PRG 2023 0 05-14    PRG 202 05-14
```

**The expectation result**

```
 FORM_NO                         REC1                           REC2
 -----------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------ 
GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD     GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD     GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD
CM59930202                      CM5993 02-02                    CM5993 02-02
99109 06 08                     99109 06-08                     99109 06-08
IM 7978 08 12                   IM7978 08-12                    IM 7978 08-12
IL01220907                      IL0122 09-07                    IL0122 09-07
PRG 2023 05 14                  PRG2023 05-14                   PRG 2023 05-14
```

Comment: Could you explain the **rule** which is supposed to return desired result? You posted sample data and query you currently use, but ... what does it do and why? There are some regular expressions, case expressions, concatenations, but you shouldn't expect us to guess that much.

Comment: no rule, use for any inbuild function, i have a number of forms and different edition dates so i showing sample data.  first, i am matched check the FORM_NO column the last four digits with the Edition_Date column. if matched then the FORM_NO column the last four digits are skipped and concatenations with the Edition_Date column else as it is show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that gives you your wanted output, you didn't mention any rule only wanted output so here it is:

```
with FOrm as 
(
select 'GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD' Form_No, '05-05' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'CM59930202' Form_No, '02-02' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select '99109 06 08' Form_No, '06-08' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'IM 7978 08 12' Form_No, '08-12' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'IL01220907' Form_No, '09-07' Edition_Date from dual
union all
select 'PRG 2023 05 14' Form_No, '05-14' Edition_Date from dual)

select Form_No,
case
    when not regexp_like(Form_No,'[0-9]{1}') then Form_No

    when regexp_like(trim(Form_No),'^[A-Za-z]{1,}[[:space:]]{1,}') then 
        regexp_substr(Form_No,'^[A-Za-z]{1,}')||regexp_substr(Form_No,'[0-9]{1,}')||' '||
        Edition_Date
    
    when regexp_like(Form_No,'^[0-9]{1,}') then Form_No
    
    when regexp_like(Form_No,'^[A-Za-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}') then
        regexp_substr(Form_No,'^[A-Za-z]{1,}')||regexp_substr(Form_No,'[0-9]{4}')||' '||
        Edition_Date
end as rec1,
case
    when not regexp_like(Form_No,'[0-9]{1}') then Form_No

    when regexp_like(trim(Form_No),'^[A-Za-z]{1,}[[:space:]]{1,}') then 
        regexp_substr(Form_No,'^[A-Za-z]{1,}')||' '||regexp_substr(Form_No,'[0-9]{1,}')||' '||
        Edition_Date
    
    when regexp_like(Form_No,'^[0-9]{1,}') then Form_No
    
    when regexp_like(Form_No,'^[A-Za-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}') then
        regexp_substr(Form_No,'^[A-Za-z]{1,}')||regexp_substr(Form_No,'[0-9]{4}')||' '||
        Edition_Date
end as rec2
from FOrm
```

RESULT:

```
FORM_NO                      REC1                        REC2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD  GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD GL-GEN-CHANGE-ENDT-MISC-OLD
CM59930202                   CM5993 02-02                CM5993 02-02
99109 06 08                  99109 06 08                 99109 06 08
IM 7978 08 12                IM7978 08-12                IM 7978 08-12
IL01220907                   IL0122 09-07                IL0122 09-07
PRG 2023 05 14               PRG2023 05-14               PRG 2023 05-14
```